# Continuous movement of a box in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have written the following code that creates a simple game where when you click an arrow on the keyboard a box moves a unit over in the game.

I am trying to make it so that if i push any of the arrow buttons the box will continue to move in that direction until another arrow is pushed. So if i push the right arrow once instead of scooting +50 pixels it will move continuously across the screen untill a different arrow is clicked and then it will go that way

```
import pygame #importing the pygame library

# some initializations
pygame.init()  # this line initializes pygame
window = pygame.display.set_mode( (800,600) ) # Create a window with   width=800 and height=600
pygame.display.set_caption( 'Rectangle move' ) # Change the window's name we create to "Rectangle move"
clock = pygame.time.Clock() # Clocks are used to track and control the frame-rate of a game (how fast and how slow the pace of the game)
                        # This line creates and initializes a clock.

# color definitions, using RBG color model.
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

# initial center position for the square (bob)
x,y = 0,0
lastKey=0
game_loop=True
while game_loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():   # loop through all events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_loop = False # change the game_loop boolean to False to quit.
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            lastKey = event.key
    #check last entered key
    #lastKey equals "LEFT", "RIGHT", "UP", "DOWN" --> do the required stuff!
    #set x coordinate minus 50 if left was pressed
    if lastKey == pygame.K_LEFT:
         x -= 50
    if lastKey == pygame.K_RIGHT:
         x += 50
    if lastKey == pygame.K_UP:
         y += 50
    if lastKey == pygame.K_DOWN:
         y -= 50
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
          x -= 50
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
          x += 50
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
          y += 50
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
          y -= 50
 # draw and update screen
 window.fill( black ) # fill the screen with black overwriting even bob.
 pygame.draw.rect( window, white, (x, y, 50, 50) ) # draw bob on the screen with new coordinates after its movement.
                                                      # the parameters are as follows: window: is the window object you want to draw on. white: the object color used to fill the rectangle
                                                      # (x,y,50,50) x is the x position of the left side of the rectangle. y is the y position of the upper side of the rectangle. 
                                                      # In other words (x,y) is the coordinate of the top left point of the rectangle.
                                                      # 50 is the width, and 50 is the height
 pygame.display.update() #updates the screen with the new drawing of the rectangle.

#fps stuff:
 clock.tick(10) # this controls the speed of the game. low values makes the game slower, and large values makes the game faster.

 pygame.quit()
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try to save the entered key into a variable and check it after your Event-Loop.
Like this:

```
#...
lastKey = None
while game_loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():   # loop through all events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_loop = False # change the game_loop boolean to False to quit.
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            lastKey = event.key
    #check last entered key
    #lastKey equals "LEFT", "RIGHT", "UP", "DOWN" --> do the required stuff!
    #set x coordinate minus 50 if left was pressed
    if lastKey == pygame.K_LEFT
         x -= 50
    #<add the other statements here>
    #(...)
```

I would recommend to not use that many if-statements. It could get a bit confusing after some time.
Check the following question out to keep your code brief:

[Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: im not sure i follow, can you give me a sample?

Comment: @NoahDukehart I gave you a simple one in the answer. ;)
Just take the hole if-else-block out of the event-handling and put it below the for-event-statement or alternately research a bit about this directory-mapping mentioned in the link to reduce the code a bit.

Comment: is this what you are saying?

Comment: mhm...not quite. Your are a new in the programming "business", aren't you?
I will update my answer if I have break at work. ;) (in about 1 hour)
In the meantime you could look up how variables work.

Comment: im trying my hardest. Im a marketing major in an upper level computer science class and its just real hard for me

Comment: Learning how to program is tuff in the beginning I understand that pretty well. :) Just don't force it to much. 'Cause you won't have fun with programming if you do. ;)

Comment: So...I updated my answer for you so that you can see what I meant. :)

Comment: im still confused so where do i put the event keys?

Comment: You store the event keys in 'lastKey = event.key'

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the *state* of your application when you press a key. So you need a variable to keep track of that state (the state is: *What direction should the box move?*).

Here's a complete, minimal example that does what you're looking for. Note the comments.

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen_r = screen.get_rect()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
rect = pygame.rect.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)

# let's start at the center of the screen
rect.center = screen_r.center

# a dict to map keys to a direction
movement = {pygame.K_UP:    ( 0, -1),
            pygame.K_DOWN:  ( 0,  1),
            pygame.K_LEFT:  (-1,  0), 
            pygame.K_RIGHT: ( 1,  0)}

move = (0, 0)

# a simple helper function to apply some "speed" to your movement
def mul10(x):
    return x * 10

while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        # try getting a direction from our dict
        # if the key is not found, we don't change 'move'
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            move = movement.get(e.key, move)

    # move the rect by using the 'move_ip' function
    # but first, we multiply each value in 'move' with 10
    rect.move_ip(map(mul10, move))

    # ensure that 'rect' is always inside the screen
    rect.clamp_ip(screen_r)
    screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('Black'))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.color.Color('White'), rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I use a `Rect` instead of keeping track of two coordinates `x` and `y`, since that allows to make use of the `move_ip` and `clamp_ip` functions to easily move the rect inside the screen.

Comment: i asked a new question

Comment: how do i find the center of the rectangles so i can get my code cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Here are two versions, the first demonstrates how to utilize an event loop to get continuous movement (similar to Sloth's solution, but a bit simpler for beginners who don't know dictionaries yet), the second one shows how to achieve this with `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

Solution 1: Check which key was pressed in the event loop and change the x and y velocities to the desired values. Then add the velocities to the `rect.x` and `rect.y` positions in the while loop.

I'd actually recommend using [vectors](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) instead of the `velocity_x` and `velocity_y` variables and another one for the actual position of your sprite. `pygame.Rect`s can't have floats as their coordinates and so a vector or separate variables for the position would be more accurate.

```
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    rect = pg.Rect(100, 200, 40, 60)
    velocity_x = 0
    velocity_y = 0
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    velocity_x = 4
                elif event.key == pg.K_a:
                    velocity_x = -4
            elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_d and velocity_x > 0:
                    velocity_x = 0
                elif event.key == pg.K_a and velocity_x < 0:
                    velocity_x = 0

        rect.x += velocity_x
        rect.y += velocity_y

        screen.fill((40, 40, 40))
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (150, 200, 20), rect)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Solution 2: Call `pygame.key.get_pressed` to check which key is currently being held down. Check if the left, right, up or down keys are held and then adjust the position of the sprite each frame.

`pygame.key.get_pressed` has the disadvantage that you can't know the order of the key presses, but the code looks a bit simpler.

```
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    rect = pg.Rect(100, 200, 40, 60)
    velocity = (0, 0)
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_d]:
            rect.x += 4
        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            rect.x -= 4

        screen.fill((40, 40, 40))
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (150, 200, 20), rect)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```